# JPA: Named query database independence

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

1. If there is named query written in JPA (`javax.persistence.NamedQuery`), is it independent of database or ORM implementation i.e Should the name query work if we change ORM implementation from hibernate to iBatis or change the databse from Oracle to mySQL?
2. Is it possible to have database specific syntax in named query? If yes then its same as native query?

Comment: see https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077875/ibatis--hibernate--and-jpa--which-is-right-for-you-.html?page=7

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have database specific syntax in named query? If yes then its same as native query?

Sure, simply use `@NamedNativeQuery`